# After bulletproofs upgrade, is scanning of the blocks faster for a balance update?

Tags: block-scanning, bulletproofs

Does bulletproofs speed up scanning of the blocks to get your updated balance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It greatly speeds up scanning of newer blocks that use bulletproofs. It does not speed up the scanning of the existing blocks if you're refreshing your wallet from scratch.